# Use raw SQL to create tables in SQLAlchemy, after which use ORM

Tags: python, database-design, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to use raw SQL rather than the TABLE construct for creating tables in SQL Alchemy?  I would still like to use the rest of SQLAlchemy though, such as the object mapper and session module.  I'm just not fond of the SQLAlchemy syntax used to create tables (I've spent too long mired in SAS and SQL to learn another!).

Many thanks, Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
connection.execute("""
CREATE TABLE ...
""")
```

You can then reflect all tables: `MetaData(dsn, reflect=True)` or `metadata_instance.reflect()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `autoload` paramater to the `Table` constructor to have it automatically load up the table definitions. There are some examples [here](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/metadata.html).